# Need to change all contents of a KnockoutJS observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a knockoutJS observable array which I created in the usual way:

```
var MyGridModel = function(items) {
var self = this;
this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
...
```

I would like to change the array to a new one based on new information. I need to change the entire array (or if I can, the entire contents to the new array, whichever is easier).

My attempt to do this is done in the following code:

```
    this.setData = function(newData)
   {
       var grid = ko.observableArray(newData);
       self.items([]);
       self.items(grid);
   }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a blank grid when I perform this operation.

Clearly I am missing something. How do I make this change work?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 0):

To update the contents of an observable array, just call it and pass the new contents to it:

```
this.setData = function(newData) {
    self.items(newData);
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. I am still getting a blank table.

Comment: @FactorThree OK. Can you edit your question to add a snippet that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.setData = function(newData)
{
    self.items.removeAll();        
    for(int i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
        self.items.push(newData[i]);
    }
}
```

Note: Each `push` will update observers.